# If $f(x)g(x) - 2015 = 0$ has at least 33 distinct solutions, prove that both f and g are polynomials of degree at least 3

Tags: polynomials

Consider two non constant polynomials, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, with coefficients in Z. if $$f(x)g(x)-2015=0$$ has at least 33 distinct solutions in Z, then show that both f and g are polynomials of degree at least 3.

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: What are your own thoughts? For instance, have you thought about what  they are actually _asking_ about here? Obviously if there are $33$ solutions, $f(x)g(x)$ must have quite a high degree (like, at least $33$). Why are they asking about as low a number as $3$?

Comment: @HenryW. non-constant ${}{}{}$

Comment: Where is this problem coming from?

Comment: Yes, I should have indicated that. That was the one bit of information I did realize, that f(x)g(x) must have a degree of at least 33. However, I am not sure why even if just f(x) had a degree of 33 (with degree of g(x) = 1) this would not be possible?

Comment: @HenryW. I am not convinced, which polynomial of degree 33 would work (even if you allow $g=1$)?

Comment: @Mirko :  if you allow $g(x) = 1$ then $f(x) = 2015+ \prod_{k=0}^n (x-k)$ is a solution (take whatever you need for $n$, 32 in this case)

Comment: @mentorship The crucial part about why $f(x)$ with degree $33$ and $g(x)$ with degree $1$ won't work probably lies in the part where it says "solutions _in_ $\Bbb Z$". Otherwise it wouldn't be too hard to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: the factorization of $2015=5\cdot13\cdot31$ must be relevant though I don't yet understand the problem. Too few factors, so few representations of $2015=65\cdot31$ etc

Comment: @Tryss:  this is why the problem says non-constant.  Presumably if we let $n=32$ in your expression we get a polynomial that is irreducible over the integers and this remains true no matter what collection of $k$'s we take.  We are to prove that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the general idea :

$2015 = 5\times 13 \times 31$

So as the polynomials are at coefficient in $\Bbb Z$, g and f will take values in this set at each root of the polynomial $P$:

$\{ \pm 1, \pm 5, \pm 13, \pm 31 ,\pm 65, \pm 155, \pm 403, \pm 2015 \}$

And every value of $g$ at a root is "conjugate" with another value of $f$ at this root (-1 goes with -2015, 31 goes with 65, etc.).

But this gives you only 16 distinct roots if your polynomial is of degree 1 (as f and g can take only once each of these values), and 32 roots if your polynomial is of degree 2, so you need at least degree 3

Comment: Oh, so sort of using Pigeon Hall principle?

Comment: @mentorship : yes, it seems to works here

Comment: @mentorship who is Pigeon Hall? I thought you spell her Pigeon Whole...

Comment: it's actually pidgeon-hole

Comment: @CarryonSmiling [I see :)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgeon)

Comment: You are missing the divisor $155$, which makes it exactly $32$ :)

Comment: This also works with $32$ distinct roots, with the same argument and a little refining.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling : hehe, I makes more sense

Comment: @Tryss I realized why linear $f$ and $g$ will have 8 solutions but can't get why quadratics haveing 2 solutions will have an effect on the number of solutions.

Comment: @Dhruv : With a quadratrics, you can't have $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = f(x_3)$, but if you have 33 different roots, you'll have at least one value that will be attained 3 times (or more)